# SDK2: Linking to portfolio items child stories from a grid

Tags: rally

I have a SDK2 Rally grid of feature level portfolio items.  I want to link directly to the list of child user stories.  The following used to work:

```
    columnCfgs: [
                    {dataIndex: 'FormattedID', text:'ID', width: 50,
                        renderer: function(value, style, item, rowIndex) {
                            var link = Rally.util.Navigation.createRallyDetailUrl(item);

                            return Ext.String.format("<a target='_top' href='{1}/userstories'>{0}</a>", value, link);
                        }
                    }
                    ....
```

This would return the following link:

```
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/<id>/detail/portfolioitem/feature/<id>/userstories
```

But recently that broke (it worked before), and now the proper link seems to be the following:

```
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/<id>/detail/portfolioitem/feature/<id>/userstories
```

See the '#' in the second link?

I would expect that Rally.util.Navigation.createRallyDetailUrl(item) would produce a working link, but no longer seems to.  Is this just a new bug, or is there a better way to do this?

I'm using 2.0p5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rally Support has reviewed this issue and it appears to in fact be a Defect. Please [File a Case with Rally Support](http://www.rallydev.com/support-resources) to track and be notified of updates concerning this issue.